# Connection to MySQL through proxy server

Tags: c#, mysql, proxy

So I'm developing an application for my school in C#. I need to know how to connect via a proxy server to the MySQL database. I've been having a look around and found the following code:

```
NetworkCredential credential=new NetworkCredential("User","Password");
WebProxy proxy=new WebProxy("10.0.0.1",808);
proxy.Credentials=credential;

MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = "Host=192.168.0.10;port=3307;user=root;password=root";
conn.Proxy=proxy;
```

However, the line `conn.Proxy=proxy;` doesn't work as `conn` doesn't contain a definition for `Proxy`.

So how do I connectt to MySQL through a proxy in C#?

Comment: I've seen some posts that suggest the the MySQL.NET connector does not support proxies. Some other third party library maybe?

Comment: Been looking online, couldn't find much apart from people posting the code snippet that I have above. I guess it's not a very common thing to do.

Comment: I noticed that as well. That code was on at least a couple different sites with no real solution other than "find another way" or "well, I'm not using a proxy, so it works fine" unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else having the problem, this is how I got around it:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HTTPPOSTsAndHTTPGETsWithWebClientAndCAndFakingAPostBack.aspx